# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] works on one server and not the other - I've compared & checked configs

Tags: php

I can't figure this out and it should be simple - I have two servers both Apache2 both php 5.3.27
both have include path .:/usr/local/lib/php but I can include files "anywhere" I choose on the server on one of them with (or whichever directory I look for:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/MyIncludes/fileToInclude.php");
```

and the other server ignores the includes completely using the same code. I'm trying to migrate existing code over to the other server. I've echo'd the document root on both and it all appears to point where I expect.

I CAN include a file on the new server as long as it's in the same directory only, with a simple

```
include("fileToInclude.php");
```

But not outside of the same directory

Based on other posts on here I've:

```
echo getcwd();
echo get_include_path();
echo $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT];
```

and on both servers and they do compare (with the exception of the different domain they each use)
I've been searching and staring at it way too long. 
????

Comment: The most reliable directory to use is `__DIR__`, which is the directory containing the script you type it in (or equivalently, `dirname(__FILE__)`, in case you're on a really old version of PHP).

Comment: SO ignoring whether the include works or not, you're saying that $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] (with quote marks) does return expected results?

Comment: @CT14.IT Yes that works on the one server that I originally had the code on.

Comment: @user371051 but writing echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; on the other server doesn't return anything?

Comment: @IMSoP  I will try/test that,  the other method always had worked, so I only relied on that in the past.

Comment: @CT14.IT  echoing  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];  returns the path I would expect to see  and on both servers. but the include itself only works on the one (original) server.

Comment: @user371051 I would conclude from that, that $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is working as expected and the issue is in relation to include. Potentially a file permission issue?

Comment: __DIR__ seems to work not sue why the other isn't but I'll not tie this up further. Thanks @IMSoP & @ CT14.IT  for your time and assistance !